# javascript apply and call methods and chain together

Tags: javascript

In this article [js log function](https://gist.github.com/bgrins/5108712?signup=true), there is a statement:
Function.prototype.apply.call(console.log, console, arguments);

I'm really confused by this statement.

1. What does it do?
2. How can I analyse this statement?
3. Or with some     thoughts or tools, I can figure it out step by step?
4. Can it be simplified to more       statements to achieve the same result? for instance:  `var temp =       Function.prototype.call(console.log, console, arguments);`       `Function.prototype.apply(temp);`

Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply is a function on the function prototype. Call is also a function on the function prototype. Apply is a function, therefore, it has call on it's prototype. All this is doing is calling the apply function.

Read more about apply here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Comment: I'm going to read the link you provided, then reply you later.

Comment: `Function.prototype.apply.call(console.log, console, arguments)`,
which equals:
`console.log.apply(console, arguments)`
or
`console.log.apply.call(console, arguments)`?

Comment: console.log.apply(console, arguments) or even simpler console.log(argument 1, argument 2, argument 3, etc...)

Answer (score 1):

> What does it do?

It calls `console.log` with `console` as `this` during the call, passing along the arguments in the
pseudo-array `arguments` as discrete arguments to the function.
So if `arguments` had `"hi", "there"` in it, it would be the same as:

```
console.log("hi", "there");
```

> How can I analyse this statement?
>
> Or with some thoughts or tools, I can figure it out step by step?

Let's start with what the `apply` and `call` functions are: They each have the ability to call a function
using a specific `this` during the call and passing arguments to that function. `apply` gets those
arguments from a single array (or anything array-like). `call` gets those arguments as individual arguments.

Normally, you'd see `apply` or `call` used like this:

```
someFunction.apply(valueForThis, ["arg1", "arg2", "arg3"]);
// or
someFunction.call(valueForThis, "arg1", "arg2", "arg3");
```

The only difference between `apply` and `call` is how they expect to get their arguments (`apply` = in
an array-like thing, `call` = as individual arguments).

So why, then, isn't that code doing this?

```
console.log.apply(console, arguments);
```

It's being cautious: `console.log` is a function provided by the host. It may not be a true JavaScript
function, and so it may not have the `apply` property.
So that code is avoiding relying on `console.log` having the `apply` property.

Which is where `Function.prototype` comes in. It's a reference to the object that is the prototype of all true JavaScript functions.
That prototype is where the `apply` and `call` properties on JavaScript functions come from.
So if we're worried that `console.log` doesn't have it (e.g., in case it doesn't inherit from `Function.prototype`), we can grab `apply` from that prototype object directly.

So the code is using `call` to call `apply`, and using `apply` to call `console.log`.

> Can it be simplified to more statements to achieve the same result?

Not really, there's not a lot we can separate. I'll try to use variable names to clarify:

```
var thisValue = console;
var functionToCall = console.log;
var applyFunction = Function.prototype.apply;
applyFunction.call(functionToCall, thisValue, arguments);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's take this one part at a time.

`Function.prototype.apply`, more commonly seen as `myBigFatFunction.apply`, lets you call a function with a different `this` context than it would normally have. The difference between `apply` and `call` is that the former takes an *array* of arguments, the latter takes direct arguments after the first. Example:

```
myStr.substring(5)
String.prototype.substring.apply(myStr, [5]);
String.prototype.substring.call(myStr, 5);
^ all equivalent
```

However, for reasons I can't fully explain myself, some browser-native functions accessible to JavaScript don't have this function as a property (eg, `console.log.apply`). It's still possible to manually call it in the same manner though; so that `console` is still `this`, when it calls `log`, and that's what the given function is doing.

The reason for all that complication is that they want to pass in the `arguments` special variable. This is a keyword that exists in all functions, which represents all arguments to the function as an array-like object (so, suitable for `Function.prototype.apply`)

Your variable suggestion would likely simply call `console.log` once with `console` as argument one, and `arguments` as variable two, and return the result, rather than give you a function in a variable. If you want a shortened reference, it's possible you could use `Function.prototype.bind`, but that could actually lengthen your code.