# Javascript call and apply methods

Tags: javascript

I am confused by this code:

`Function.prototype.apply.call(Math.floor, undefined, [1.75]); // 1`

I read this post [javascript apply and call methods and chain together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34229878/javascript-apply-and-call-methods-and-chain-together) and I understand the meaning of chaining apply and call methods together.

However, I am still confused about the syntax. The correct syntax for call is `function.call(thisArg, arg1, arg2, ...)`.
But in this case, why could the call method take these **three** parameters (`target`, `thisArgument`, `argumentsList`), which is the same as `Reflect.apply(target, thisArgument, argumentsList)`?

Comment: Because it's actually passing the argument to `apply()`, which does take that.

Comment: So `thisArg = target`, `arg1 = thisArgument`, `arg2 = argumentList`. Now insert them!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, call method can take all comma separated arguments and pass it to the called method. 
While as you see here `(target, thisArgument, argumentsList)` Second two arguments work as arguments for apply method and we know that apply method gonna need an array of argument, we have sent third parameter as an array.

So here the execution can be simplified to :

```
Math.floor.apply(undefined, [1.75]);
```

Or simply `Math.floor(1.75) // Obv with undefined as reference of this`

Answer (score 2):

```
    Function.prototype.apply.call(Math.max, undefined, [1,75]); // 1
```

code above change **thisArgu** in **Function.prototype.apply** to **Math.max**

let's talk about **change thisArgu in Function.prototype.apply to Math.max**

noramlly, **this** in **Function.prototype.apply** should be **Function.prototype**

so **change thisArgu in Function.prototype.apply to Math.max** means:

change **Function.prototype** to **Math.max** if met 'this' when executing in Function.prototype.apply()

so code above can be understood like this when execute and meet 'this' :

```
    Math.max.apply(undefined,[1,75])
```

now you understand?

if we go on ,you will find

```
    Math.max.apply(undefined,[1,75])
```

can be understood like:

```
    Window.max(1,75)//error;
```

so , i guess 'this' word doesn't exist in Math.max function content,so it gets no error;

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for `call()` is:

```
someFunctionOrMethod.call(...)
```

So, this code is calling the `apply` method of the `Function` type.

```
// Call the "apply()" method
Function.prototype.apply.call()

// With the following arguments passed to "apply"
(Math.floor, undefined, [1.75])
```